# HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections (CodeIgniter problem?)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to use the XMLWriter class in PHP to generate XML.  I am working in CodeIgniter.  When I try to output XML, I get this error (HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections).  What does it mean and what do I need to do to fix it?  I am using this class here: http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10356853.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What's your output call look like? That error usually means you're trying to save to an http url, e.g. like:

```
$myobj->save('http://example.com/path/file.xml');
```

which generally will fail. This requires an HTTP upload, but provides none of the specifics necessary to perform one. Should it be a PUT? A POST? What's the fieldname the receiving server is expecting? etc...

Comment: I am using an absolute path.  Should I use a relative one instead?

Comment: Has nothing to do with absolute/relative. If you're using an http url as your filename, you'll get the error.

Comment: It was the path that was the problem.  The relative path works just fine.  Thanks, Marc B.